# What abbreviation does they use for nominal voltage (Un) in Russian?

Tags: voltage

I need to translate the "Un" symbol for Russian client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd go for "Uн" / "Vн", or "Uном" / "Vном" if you can afford longer labels. Note that equipment I have seen would cite the nominal voltage itself (i.e. "220/230 В", "380/400 В", "10кВ" etc.) without calling it nominal.

Russian Wikipedia has an article about [nominal voltage](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), but it doesn't mention any official abbreviations.

Comment: i swear , i entered this question just to see how would answer and i expected you . :)